# opencv error when compiling caffe-1.0 on ubuntu14.04

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu, caffe

I came into a bug when compiling the latest caffe-1.0 with opencv.
I compiled it on ubuntu14.04 using gcc-4.8.5 with cuda8.0 and cudnn5.1.
I tried different versions of opencv(2.4.8, 2.4.13, 3.2.0) but the error continued.
The error is as follows:

```
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4127:9: error: expected identifier before ‘float’
FLOAT=REAL, //!< synonym or REAL
^
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4127:9: error: expected ‘}’ before ‘float’
In file included from examples/cpp_classification/classification.cpp:3:0:
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4127:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘=’ token
FLOAT=REAL, //!< synonym or REAL
^
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4140:22: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘)’ token
CV_WRAP FileNode();
^
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4142:14: error: expected unqualified-id 
before ‘const’
FileNode(const CvFileStorage* fs, const CvFileNode* node);
^
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4142:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4144:14: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘const’
FileNode(const FileNode& node);
^
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4144:14: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘const’
/usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp:4146:49: error: non-member function ‘cv::FileNode cv::operator[](const string&)’ cannot have cv-qualifier
FileNode operator[](const string& nodename) const;
```

Answer (score 0):

I sloved the problem myself.

The error occured because I compiled and installed the latest OpenBlas library, version 0.2.19. The file cblas.h caused the opencv problem.

I just renamed the cblas.h in /usr/local/include so the command make will use the cblas.h in /usr/include and succeeded finally.